# mplayer treating ogg files as if empty

Tags: mplayer, ogg-vorbis

When I try to play a .ogg file with mplayer, nothing happens. mplayer leaves the following output in my terminal:

```
jcast@jcast-Galago-Pro:~$ mplayer '/home/jcast/Music/Wade Bowen/The Given/Saturday Night.ogg'
MPlayer 1.5+svn38423-2build1 (Debian)
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing /home/jcast/Music/Wade Bowen/The Given/Saturday Night.ogg.
libavformat version 60.3.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (vorbis), -aid 0, Saturday Night
Load subtitles in /home/jcast/Music/Wade Bowen/The Given/
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 60.3.100 (external)
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 160.0 kbit/5.67% (ratio: 20000->352800)
Selected audio codec: [ffvorbis] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg Vorbis)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A: 209.7 (03:29.6) of 209.7 (03:29.6) ??,?% 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

But it exits nearly immediately, without playing any audio at all.

This happens with all the .ogg files I've tested, but I haven't tested every .ogg file in my music library.

The same files do produce output just fine with ogg123.

I would be surprised if this has been happening for a while and I haven't noticed (I have 1345 .mp3 files and 1411 .ogg files) but I can't remember what could have changed to affect it recently.

The relevant package versions I can find are:

```
$ dpkg -l mplayer
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version                Architecture Description
+++-==============-======================-============-==================================
ii  mplayer        2:1.5+svn38423-2build1 amd64        movie player for Unix-like systems

$ dpkg -l '*vorbis*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version             Architecture Description
+++-====================-===================-============-==========================================================
ii  libvorbis0a:amd64    1.3.7-1build2       amd64        decoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
ii  libvorbis0a:i386     1.3.7-1build2       i386         decoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
ii  libvorbisenc2:amd64  1.3.7-1build2       amd64        encoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
ii  libvorbisenc2:i386   1.3.7-1build2       i386         encoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
ii  libvorbisfile3:amd64 1.3.7-1build2       amd64        high-level API for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
ii  libvorbisidec1:amd64 1.2.1+git20180316-7 amd64        Integer-only Ogg Vorbis decoder, AKA "tremor"
ii  vorbis-tools         1.4.2-1build2       amd64        several Ogg Vorbis tools
```